# Make a UITableView disappear temporarily?

Tags: objective-c, iphone

I have a `UITableView` overlaying over a `UIMapView` so you can select a specific building from the table and it shows you where it is on the map. Now that is working fine, but when the iPhone is in portrait mode there is not a lot of space to see the map so I am trying to put in a button to make the table appear and disappear as the user wants.

Does anybody know if this is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// To hide
table_view.hidden = YES;

// To show
table_view.hidden = NO;
```

Comment: I'm hitting myself over the head now, I should have seen that. Thanks for the help.

Calaghan001.